# cakephp - order by timestamp DESC not working

Tags: cakephp

I have a table called posts that stores all the posts . It has two columns "Created" and "Modified" .

Below is my query in the model :

```
$options = [
            'conditions' => [
                'circle_id'                => $my_circle_list,
                'team_id'                  => $this->current_team_id,
                'modified BETWEEN ? AND ?' => [$start, $end],
            ],
            'order'      => ['modified'=> 'desc'],
            'limit'      => $limit,
            'fields'     => ['post_id'],
        ];
        $res = $this->find('list', $options);
```

Now i want the latest edited posts on top and below is what my mysql dump reads like :

```
SELECT `Post`.`id` FROM `db`.`posts` AS `Post`   WHERE `Post`.`id` IN (125, 124) AND `Post`.`del_flg` = '0'   ORDER BY `Post`.`modified` desc  LIMIT 20
```

If i run this query in my database editor ,it gives my the correct output , but in my controller the ordering changes again , this is something i figured after i debugged the array values.

Would be helpful if anyone could tell me if there's any specific reason behind this . The call to this model method from the controller is done in a conventional manner  .

Answer (score 0):

When using `$this->find()` after Cake has queried the database with the generated SQL it calls the [`afterFind()` method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) on the model where it can manipulate the data. This is the mostly likely place for the ordering to have been modified.